# Change textarea into <li> element when done editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
var counter=0;
function appendText(){
    var text = $("#text").val();

    if ( $("#text").val() ){

    var textArea = "<div class='divex'> <textarea id='t"+counter+"'>"+text+"</textarea><button id='b"+
    counter+"'name='t"+counter+"' >edit</button> <button onClick='moveUp()' id='updiv'>Up:></button></div>";    
    $("#text").val();
    $("#addedText").after(textArea);
    $("#t"+counter).clear;    
    $("#t"+counter).attr('readonly','readonly');
    $("#b"+counter).bind('click',makeAreaEditable);
    $("#text").val('');

    counter++;
    }
    else{
    }   
};                                                                  

var makeAreaEditable = function()
{
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;
    var button = $("#"+target.id);
    button.text("OK");
    button.unbind('click');
    button.bind('click',saveEdit);
    var targetArea = $("#"+target.name);
    targetArea.removeAttr('readonly');


};                                                      


var saveEdit =  function()
{
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;
    var button = $("#"+target.id);
    button.text("edit");
    button.unbind('click');
    button.bind('click',makeAreaEditable);
    var targetArea = $("#"+target.name);
    targetArea.attr('readonly','readonly');

};
```

The html looks like this:

Add text

```
    <div id="addedText" style="float:left">
    </div>
```

I want to change this script so that : when i click the add text button - the text will be added as an `li` element when i click ok it will bring the textarea and at save back to li. Thanks!

I've done it! here is the final code:

```
var makeAreaEditable = function()
{
    var liid = $(this).parent().find('li').attr('id');
    var text = $("#"+liid).html();
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;
    var button = $("#"+target.id);
    button.text("OK");
    button.unbind('click');
    button.bind('click',saveEdit);
    var targetArea = $("#"+target.name);
    targetArea.replaceWith('<textarea>'+text+'</textarea>');    
};                                                      


var saveEdit =  function()
{
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;
    var button = $("#"+target.id);
    var textarea = $(this).parent().find('textarea');
    var text = textarea.val();
    button.text("edit");
    button.unbind('click');
    var targetArea = button.parent().find('textarea');
    var textid = target.name;
    targetArea.replaceWith("<li id='"+textid+"' style='list-style-type:none;'>"+text+"</li>");
};
```

Comment: A textarea can contain HTML. This could well break your li tag.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: Thanks marc B.. I still have a problem i changed the makeAreaEditable function and added targetArea.replaceWith('<textarea></textarea>'), the problem is How can i also get the text in it so that i edit it

Comment: I feel like I didn't understand the question. Maybe you could be more specific about what you're trying to do. I started from scratch in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/8nTXB/

Comment: Well when i press Add text the text should appear like list element + the edit button.. when  i press edit a textarea must apear with the list value in it so i can edit the text when i press ok it should turn to the list element again with the new text value... I modify the code here: var textArea = "<div class='divex'> <li style='list-style-type:none;'id='t"+counter+"'>"+text+"</li><button id='b"+
 counter+"'name='t"+counter+"' >edit</button> </div>";

Comment: It's pretty trivial to code yourself, however there are also libraries that handle it all for you: [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Comment: i resolved the problem i've posted the 2 changed functions up. thanks for your help. regards